# How to inherit object and initialize : Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, methods

I created an object called Model that has some methods. I want to import Model into Mediator to use its methods there. But when I try to do this in `Mediator.m` I keep getting errors:
`Initializer element is not a compile-time constant` & `No known class method for selector 'add'`

I'm confused at to what these error are getting at. Researching them has not made things more clear.

Model.h

```
@interface Model : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger tally;
-(int) add;

@end
```

Model.m

```
 #import "Model.h"
    @interface Model ()
    
    @end
    
    @implementation Model
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tally = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (int)add {
    self.tally = self.tally + 1;
    return self.tally;
}


@end
```

Mediator.h

```
@interface MediatorController : NSObject
    
- (int)addOne;

@end
```

Mediator.m

```
@interface MediatorController ()


@end

@implementation MediatorController

Model *model = [[Model alloc] init];      <<<<<<< "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant"

- (int)addOne {
    return [Model add];        <<<<<< "No known class method for selector 'add"
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need a `model` property on your `MediatorController`

```
@interface MediatorController : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) Model* model; //<-- Here

- (int)addOne;
- (int)subtractOne;
- (void)setValue:(int)value;
- (int)value;

@end
```

Then, you need an `init` method -- right now, you're trying to write your `model =` at the top level of the implementation, which doesn't work -- it needs to be inside a method.

Lastly, instead of calling `add` on `Model` (which is the class), call it on `self.model`, which is the instance of the class.

```
@implementation MediatorController

- (instancetype)init { //< -- Here
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.model = [Model new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (int)addOne {
    return [self.model add];
}

@end
```

You'll end up with a few compiler warnings because you haven't implemented the rest of the methods yet (`subtractOne`, `setValue`, etc), but this will get you started.